# Can a domain owner be hidden?

Tags: hosting, dns

I am not sure if this question belongs here or superuser (or other).  If not - please let me know and I'll erase the question.

A friend of mine wishes to buy a domain but keep his name hidden.  Is there a secure way of doing so?

Comment: belongs on superuser or serverfault. Oh, and it depends on your country's laws. China requires a way to identify the owner of a domain registered within its borders. That's one of the reasons godaddy pulled out of China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, It's called **Privacy Protection** and  that's possible if your Domain Registrar supports this. Now a days almost all registrars support this. I buy my domains from [answerable.com](http://www.answerable.com/content.php?action=free_services) which is very economical and provides privacy protection as well.

http://www.answerable.com/content.php?action=free_services

Answer (score 2):

If you buy the domain through [godaddy.com](http://godaddy.com/), there's an option of hiding your info. I believe they charge for that service though.